# Unexpected scroll behaviour in angular

Tags: angular, scroll

I encountered unexpected scroll behaviour like below

If I deleted table tag in HTML then it works fine

But honestly, I don't know really why.

I didn't code anything related to scroll event and with TABLE TAG

[**Chrome Debug Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6QPI.jpg)

There isn't just one behaviour
These scroll event occur 7~10 times

[**Searching some scroll event that i coded in WebStorm**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJHAs.png)

**->Never**

[**I deleted this table tag in HTML, then works fine**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGeGu.png)

**-> I didn't code 'any' Typescript or anything with that table tag**

I don't know really why

It is hard to explain why this event happens. Could anybody give some debug instruction guide to me ?

Because, really.. I don't know how to debug this

Comment: what is numberArray(5) returning?

Comment: @danday74 just return Array(5);

Comment: what does JSON.stringify(numberArray(5)) return?

Comment: @danday74 "[null,null,null,null,null]" it's just for looping 5 times

Comment: @danday74 <tr  *ngFor="let item of numberArray(5);  index as i "> Now is this correct? After fixed this, but scroll event still fired

Comment: looks good like that

Comment: @danday74 sorry but scroll event still fired

Comment: does it work if you use a smaller number than 5? Also see alternative code in my answer - start from the basics and build up slowly, adding your classes one by one to identify what is causing the issue

Comment: still it doesn't work if i use smaller number than 5. I saw your answer. still doesn't work but I'll try your suggestion. Thank you but it's so pain to figure this bug out

Comment: @danday74 This bug is fired when reload... at localhost:4200/p/1 After i go home (localhost:4200 ) and navigate to localhost:4200/shops/p/1 then this bug is gone.. Eventhough, I reloaded this page at localhost:4200/shops/p/1 now it works fine. Really wired,, wired

Answer (score 0):

```
let i = index
```

is wrong, depending on your Angular version, newer versions use

```
index as i
```

see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

You could do:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2,3,4]">
    <td>{{i}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```